# how to remove side menu ,header and footer in admin panel for custom module

Tags: admin, magento2

i am developing one custom admin module.i have created the grid.that is displaying as new tab in product cataloge edit page .But if you observe the another tab called Related Products, Up-Sells, and Cross-Sells -->add related product .if we click on this one side window comes .
How to implement that kind of window in our custom module

Comment: Please show the code! We cannot help you by just imagining your code in our mind.

Comment: Hi Toan Nguyen .Actually the problem i am facing is  this .Please me help with this issue.https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7991